# Using awk to shuffle text files

Tags: bash, file-io, awk

I am hoping to write a short bash script that uses awk to shuffle the contents of three files and adds an extra line with some text as the fourth line. For example:

**File 1:**

```
one.0
one.1
one.2
one.3
```

**File 2:**

```
two.0
two.1
two.2
two.3
```

**File 3:**

```
three.0
three.1
three.2
three.3
```

**Desired Results:**

```
one.0
two.0
three.0
sometext
one.1
two.1
three.1
sometext
one.2
two.2
three.2
sometext
one.3
two.3
three.3
sometext
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you REALLY mean shuffle (rearrange into a random order) or do you mean merge? Where does the extra text come from - is the script supposed to generate random text? Do the files always have exactly the same number of lines and, if not, what should the output be?

Comment: I think in card play this is called perfect shuffle, but more proper term would be interleave.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I was struggling with what to search for when looking this question up. If anyone knows the exact terminology it would be great. Perfect shuffle? Interleave? Merge?

Answer (score 5):

```
$ cat a
a0
a1
a2
a3

$ cat b
b0
b1
b2
b3

$ cat c
c0
c1
c2
c3

$ paste -d '\n' a b c | awk '1; NR % 3 == 0 {print "some text"}'
a0
b0
c0
some text
a1
b1
c1
some text
a2
b2
c2
some text
a3
b3
c3
some text
```

Comment: smart.  perhaps a variation might be `paste ... | sed '3~3asome text'`

Comment: This seems like a great solution. Short and effective. Efficiency is important in what I am doing. Can you comment on quickly this will execute compared to the code below?

Comment: ericstevens26101, the best is to try it on a test data set large enough to give meaningful timing results and see how each performs in your environment! And be sure to try with @karakfa 's very elegant alternative using `sed`, and now you have an all-awk alternative from James Brown, as well. If the files are _extremely_ large it could be good to note that Kent's solution will start by reading everything into memory. Let us know what you discover!

Answer (score 1):

This awk codes is gonna do what you want:

```
awk 'f!=FILENAME{++idx;f=FILENAME}{a[idx][FNR]=$0}
    END{rows=length(a[1])
    for(r=1;r<=rows;r++){
        for(i=1;i<=idx;i++) {
            print a[i][r]
        }
        print "sometext"
    }
}' f1 f2 f3
```

Comment: This seems like a great solution. It does seem a little more complex than the solution provided above. Efficiency is important in what I am doing. Can you comment on quickly this will execute compared to the code above?

Answer (score 0):

One in awk using `getline`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { 
           while( (getline line < ARGV[i+1]) >0 ) {  # read from file refering ARGV
               i=++i%(ARGC-1);                       # ARGV iteration
               print line (i?"":"\nsome text")       # print line and "some text" when needed
           }
       }' f1 f2 f3
one.0
two.0
three.0
some text
one.1
two.1
three.1
some text
one.2
two.2
three.2
some text
one.3
two.3
three.3
some text
```